# boost::instrusive::list with the auto-unlink hook: can I use a value in the list to determine if the list has exactly one element?

Tags: c++, boost, intrusive-containers

I have a `boost::intrusive::list<Foo, constant_time_size<false>>`, where `Foo` inherits from the `list_base_hook<auto_unlink>` hook. With a list element `foo`, I am able to get its iterator by calling `list::s_iterator_to(foo)`. My question is how I can traverse the list with this iterator. In particular, is there a way to tell if this element is the only one in the list?

The source suggests `list` uses a `cicular_list_algorithms` in its value traits and perhaps I can use the following test?

```
auto itr1 = list_t::s_iterator_to(foo);
auto itr2 = list_t::s_iterator_to(foo);
&(*++itr1) == &(*--itr2);
```

It looks quite hacky but it seeminly works. I'm not sure if it is correct and idiomatic. Can somebody please advise?

The complete listing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

typedef list_base_hook<link_mode<auto_unlink> > auto_unlink_hook;

class Foo : public auto_unlink_hook
{
    int int_;
    public:
    Foo(int i = 0)   :  int_(i)  {}
    int  get_int()    { return int_; }
    void unlink()     {  auto_unlink_hook::unlink(); }
    bool is_linked()  {  return auto_unlink_hook::is_linked();  }
};

int main()
{
    typedef list<Foo, constant_time_size<false>> ListType;
    ListType l;
    Foo foo1{42};
    l.push_back(foo1);

    auto itr1 = ListType::s_iterator_to(foo1);
    auto itr2 = ListType::s_iterator_to(foo1);
    std::cout << (&(*++itr1) == &(*--itr2)) << std::endl;

    Foo foo2{43};
    l.push_back(foo2);
    itr1 = ListType::s_iterator_to(foo1);
    itr2 = ListType::s_iterator_to(foo1);
    std::cout << (&(*++itr1) == &(*--itr2)) << std::endl;

    foo1.unlink();

    return 0;
}
```

Yes, I do realize dereferencing `++itr1` and `--itr1` is wrong. Is there any way that I can compare the addresses of the underlying nodes directly? I imagine `foo` has both links to its predecessor and successor and they should be equal to each other if `foo` is the only element.

Comment: Why not compare against `--the_list.end()`?  When you say "the last one in the list" do you mean "it is at the end of the list" or "the list has only one element"?

Comment: I should've been clearer. `foo` is obtained from another container and when i get it, i don't have a reference to the list any more. Of course I can store a reference along with every `foo` objects, but that will probably be an overkill. I meant "the list has only one element".

Comment: I see, I've edited your question a little to make it more clear.  Would you please post a complete working example program we can play with?

Comment: You can not. In order to do so you need a reference to container (which is not stored in `auto_unlink` hook). And you can not dereference `++itr1` or `--itr1` without prior check for iterator validity.

Answer (score 1):

I tried these, and it worked. However, it is tightly coupled with the implementation details. The idea is to get the underlying node pointer from the value and compare the pointers.

```
typedef list<Foo, constant_time_size<false>> ListType;                                    
ListType l;                                                                               
Foo foo1{42};                                                                             
l.push_back(foo1);                                                                        

ListType::const_node_ptr cur = ListType::value_traits::to_node_ptr(foo1);                 
std::cout << (ListType::node_traits::get_previous(cur) == ListType::node_traits::get_next(cur)) << std::endl;

Foo foo2{43};                                                                             
l.push_back(foo2);                                                                        
std::cout << (ListType::node_traits::get_previous(cur) == ListType::node_traits::get_next(cur)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Those are not "implementation details". They're implementation mechanics, and you're using only documented traits that are at your disposal. Just consider hiding the complexity in a friendly helper function and writing it as generic as possible

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My point is that a doubly linked list is not necessarily circular. An alternative implementation could also define that the head and tail are null.

Comment: Ah. Yeah. That's a good point. I assumed that was the documented behaviour. If it isn't, then DO NOT use this, because you're simply running into unspecified or undefined behaviour

Comment: Just glancing at the docs, if you make sure you're using http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/circular_list_algorithms.html you should be fine